# why is my laravel can't detect to my database on localhost

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

My project won't detect my database on localhost. If I test my database connection it will show "can't connect". No matter how many times I ask chatGPT I still can't solve this nonsense problem.

I already changed from XAMPP to Laragon but the problem is still there - I get a pop out messege that said "unable to connect". I already made multiple changes to `env` and `database.php` files, reviewing them line by line but have seem no problem.

[image: the screenshot of the pop messege]

Comment: Can you share the changes to `database.php` **and** the `.env` file? (use xxxx for password if needed) Add this info to the question, not in a comment down in this area. Is the correct port specified (if other than the default) looks like `:8000`, if configured that way? ... typically it is 3306. Not enough details/info to assist at the moment. Maybe try to run `php artisan optimize:clear` between config changes to ensure something cached is not working against you.

Comment: `No matter how many times I ask chatGPT`...it's not clear why you think ChatGPT is going to know what the correct database settings on your computer are. It's not particularly clear why you think we're going to know either. But it looks like you aren't entering the right ones. Perhaps your root account has a password? Also what code is this from? It should be giving you a more precise error message than that, if it wants to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should setting the port, database, username , and password in .env file with correct setting. It means you should have user to access database and the database